# Remove selected row index object from NSMutableArray and add to another NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

I populated a tableview with data from an NSMutableArray, everything is working fine. When I select a cell (didSelectRowAtIndex) this item is removed from the array, as it is supposed to do. Now I  want this exact same object to be added in another NSMutableArray.

In short: remove the selected object from array 01 and add the selected object to array 02.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_array01 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_array02 addobject?????];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the object to the second array before removing it from the first. Here's a way to do this with two lines of code:

```
[_array02 addObject:[_array01 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[_array01 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In a more complex case where you might need to perform some operation on the object, you could instead get a reference to the object and move it to the other array like this:

```
id myObject = [_array01 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[myObject setTitle:@"new title"]; // example of modifying the object before moving it
[_array02 addObject:myObject];
[_array01 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Note that in the second example here, you are not the owner of `myObject` according to Objective-C memory management rules. You simply have a reference to it. The `myObject` is actually owned by `_array01` and then `_array02`.